# Very strange issue during downloading user's FB profile pictures on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-fql

I develop the app for iPhone and use Facebook API to do some social activity.
I have to download user's profile picture, so I wrote the code to get its URL via FQL and to download it.

At first look all seemed to be well and my code worked, but after few days I've noticed that user's picture can not be downloaded. The FBSession opens correctly, the FQL query performs without any error and returns correct URL, but my application couldn't get image data (**[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:] or NSURLConnection always began to return nil data in all cases with 'request time out' error**). So I tried to delete my app from iPhone device and to clean Facebook data, but nothing helped me except deleting and recreating my app account at the Facebook Developers portal. 
At the moment this strange situation has repeated: initially all functionality had worked as expected but after a while it has began to fail downloading of the user's picture. So I don't know what to do.

- Also I've noticed that the official Facebook App since some critical
  moment can't download users profile picture too. So both my app and
  Facebook app can't download user's profile picture for now.
- Also all continues to work correctly at Simulator. The issue happens
  only at my iPhone device.
- Also if I tries to download another picture (I have checked with user cover
  image) all seems to be ok!

So can anybody help me to fix this issue? Thanks in advance!

All code is below.

1) Open FB session

```
FBSessionStateHandler fbCompletion = ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error)
{
    if (session.isOpen == NO || error != nil)
        authCompletion(NO, error);
    else
        authCompletion(YES, error);
    [[FBSession activeSession] setStateChangeHandler:nil];
};

NSArray *readPermissions = @[@"basic_info", @"user_photos"];

BOOL cachedToken = [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:readPermissions allowLoginUI:NO completionHandler:nil];
if (cachedToken)
{
    authCompletion(YES, nil);
}
else
{
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:readPermissions allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             [[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];
             [FBSession renewSystemCredentials:^(ACAccountCredentialRenewResult result, NSError *error) {
                 [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:readPermissions allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:fbCompletion];
             }];
         }
         else
             fbCompletion(session, status, error);
     }];
}
```

2) Perform FQL query and get URL

```
NSString *query = @"SELECT id,width,height,real_height,real_width, url FROM profile_pic WHERE id=me() AND width=260 AND height=260";
NSDictionary *params = @{@"q":query};
FBRequest *usersPictureRequest = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"fql" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"GET"];

FBRequestConnection *fbRequestConnection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] initWithTimeout:k_FBRequesTimeout];
[fbRequestConnection addRequest:usersPictureRequest completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        NSURL *pictureURL = result[@"data.url"];
        [self downloadPictureWithURL:pictureURL];
    }];
[fbRequestConnection start];
```

3) Download the picture data:

```
NSBlockOperation *downloadOp = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:pictureURL options:0 error:&error];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData scale:scale];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        pictureHandler(image != nil ? image : defaultPicture);
    });
    [NetworkActivityIndicator hide];
}];
[self.operationQueue addOperation:downloadOp];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a very vague recollection about myself having issues downloading facebook pictures but unfortunatly can't now recollect the details.

I am using the graph api to fetch a thumbnail picture which  is working ok, perhaps you could switch to using similar if it meets your needs. You should be able to change the ?type= to get a different size than I am fetching.

```
- (void) fetchFbImageForContact:(MyContact*) targetContact
{
    NSString* graphRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",  @"https://graph.facebook.com/",
                              targetContact.fbid,
                              @"/picture?type=square"];
    FBRequest *fbRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath: graphRequest];
    [fbRequest startWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *theError)
     {
         NSDictionary<FBGraphObject> *dict = (NSDictionary<FBGraphObject> *) result;
         if (dict)
         {
             NSString* urlAsString = [dict objectForKey:@"id"];
             if ([urlAsString length] > 0)
             {
                 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlAsString];
                 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
                 targetContact.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
             }
         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this has not helped me.
I've fetched URL as in my solution but it's downloading fails too.

Answer (score 0):

The best and most easier approch is to use the [FBProfilePictureView](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBProfilePictureView/)

Get the user id from the response and just set the property **profileID**

Comment: I can't use it as I have to crop image with circle path so I need raw image to prepocess it before display.
Also I am sure that FBProfilePictureView will fail as original Facebook app fails too.

Comment: well you have the view instance ..you can make it into round